# Error: connect EADDRNOTAVAIL

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

All of a sudden (this was working fine last week) I've started getting `Error sending mail: Error: connect EADDRNOTAVAIL` when trying to send emails with [Nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer).

The error is really vague and I'm not quite sure what `EADDRNOTAVAIL` means. If anybody could shed some light on this error, that would be great!

Comment: check if the port you're connecting to is correct

Answer (score 8):

I've been bugged by this problem for over half a day now. Here's the solution!

Nodemailer has just been through a major update and the format in which the transporter is specified has changed. So instead of

```
var smtpTransport=nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{host:'some host',port:25});
```

it is now just

```
var smtpTransport=nodemailer.createTransport({host:'some host',port:25});
```

Comment: your hack works fine also for me, thanks to share it ;)

Comment: Despite it's not an hack, as said by @Zauker.. that's the solution! :)

Answer (score 2):

This link (http://www.toptip.ca/2010/02/linux-eaddrnotavail-address-not.html) seems like it might help. Basically it says that under load your mailer, which opens an outgoing connection, exhausts the local ports available, and suggests ways to increase. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

The error can be, when there are a large number of connections and the net.core.somaxconn buffer is exhausted.

If there are enough resources on the server, just increase it:
sysctl net.core.somaxconn=8000